# Is there basename() equivalent in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, path

[basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) in PHP returns the file name of a path.

Is there a way to do this within the `SELECT` statement of a MySQL Query? It would be nice to have this so I can apply `ORDER BY` directly to it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to get the last element after a specific delimiter, in this case a slash. This can also be used with a backslash, simply use `"\\"` in that case.

```
SELECT
    Path,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Path, '/', -1) AS FileName
FROM
    files
```

**Example result row:**

> Path = downloads/apps/file1.exe
>   FileName = file1.exe

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer above, it is possible to make this into a mysql function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `basename`(path VARCHAR(512)) RETURNS varchar(512) CHARSET latin1 
BEGIN
    return SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1), '\\', -1);
END
```