# How to get a filename's extension in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm importing records into a system that has a separate column for a file's extension, e.g. `jpg`. How can I use MySQL string handling to extract the extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get the last part of the string that follows a `.`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('my/big/file_name.example', '.', -1); -- returns 'example'
```

I referred to this question: [Is there basename() equivalent in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166278/is-there-basename-equivalent-in-mysql)